# error while installing python functools32 on ubuntu 16.04 using python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, functools

I tried to install python functools on ubuntu 16.04 machine and I recieved this error

```
Collecting functools32
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/60/6ac26ad05857c601308d8fb9e87fa36d0ebf889423f47c3502ef034365db/functools32-3.2.3-2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    This backport is for Python 2.7 only.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-a7fm4qrj/functools32/
```

I also tried to install from [github link](https://github.com/michilu/python-functools32.git). It still failed. Got the below error.

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/michilu/python-functools32.git
  Cloning https://github.com/michilu/python-functools32.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-gyj6sclc
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    This backport is for Python 2.7 only.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-gyj6sclc/
```

How do i overcome this issue and install functools?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Functools are installed by default in Python 3:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

The error you are receiving seems to be because you're trying to install the python 2.7 backport of functools, so the error message you're getting makes sense.

Start a python command prompt and type `import functools`, if that works without errors - you've already got functools installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installation not needed in Python 3, just use this:

```
from functools import *
```